# Change /dev/video6 into /dev/video0

Tags: linux

Is it possible to change the video device for eg a webcam form `/dev/video6` to `/dev/video0`? Can that be achieved by a command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always manually rename the device file but that change won't be permanent. To make it clean and permanent you will need to add a udev rule. You can find documentation, for example for Arch Linux, [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udev#Video_devices). The udev rules should apply to all current Linux distributions.

Answer (score 1):

Can you just symlink `/dev/video6` to `/dev/video0`? That is, `ln -s /dev/video6 /dev/video0`. If so, since the link is in `/dev` you'd need to recreate the link whenever your system boots.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try:

```
mv /dev/video6 /dev/video0
```