# Android Emulator: Unable to start webcam to capture picture in emulator

Tags: java, android, android-studio, emulation, android-virtual-device

I have created an armeabi API 21 emulator in the AVD manager in Android Studio, set it to use the webcam as a front camera, and launched it.
The problem is that it's not able to open it, as I'm getting this error:

```
emulator: ERROR: camera_device_start_capturing: VIDIOC_STREAMON on camera '/dev/video0' has failed: Timer expired
emulator: ERROR: _camera_client_query_start: Cannot start camera '/dev/video0' for NV21[640x480]: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

How can I solve this?

The webcam works normally using other software. The operative system is Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Hi Johnson, what dev tools do you mean?

Comment: Same issue here - have you found a solution so far.
In my case it was AndroidStudio.

Comment: Hi Jon, no I haven't solved this problem yet. What was the issue?

Comment: It is weird - when I start the camera from vlc it works perfectly. But when using the Android's emulator - it fails. With the same error message. So, time for a bounty!

Comment: I'm using the same OS, so I have added it to the edit

Comment: Did you see this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14012924/android-how-to-use-webcam-in-emulator

Comment: It's already set like that, thank you anyway

Comment: does the webcam appear when you access the emulator command line with `-webcam list`?

Comment: Yes, the cameras are detected. It even realizes it when I switch from my built-in camera to an additional, external camera.

Comment: It seems that the `Inappropriate ioctl` error can be related to the driver for some webcams. [This page](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=17308&p=178372) discusses the error in a different context. One idea: use Gstreamer to redirect /dev/video0 to a different pipe which the Android emulator uses as a webcam input - see [this stackexchange post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5452/manipulating-dev-video).

Comment: Is it working with the emulated camera?

Answer (score 22):

In Android Studio, go to AVD Manager, click on edit (pencil) button in Actions. After that, in next appearing window, click on Advance settings, and then scroll down and in Camera options, select webcam for front and back.

Comment: As I said, I configured the emulator to use the front camera. Thanks anyway

Comment: I read a warning hat you must not name the same camera twice in AVD Manager.  So selecting webcam for front AND back would run afoul that rule.

Answer (score 12):

To enable Camera in your Android Emulator, just add following highlighted code in your AVD’s config.ini file. You can find the `config.ini` file under your `<userdirectory>/.android` folder.

File: `~/.android/config.ini`

```
hw.lcd.density=160<br>
skin.name=HVGA<br>
skin.path=platforms\android-9\skins\HVGA<br>
hw.cpu.arch=arm<br>
abi.type=armeabi<br>
vm.heapSize=24<br>
image.sysdir.1=platforms\android-9\images\<br>
hw.camera=yes<br>
sdcard.size=64M<br>
```

In case you don’t find the `config.ini` file or want to enable Camera support through Android SDK and AVD Manager do the following:

Open Android SDK and AVD Manager:

1. **Add SD Card in AVD**
   In the SD Card setting, set the value for Size. To enable camera, the SD Card must be enabled in Emulator.
2. **Add Camera Support in Hardware under AVD**
   Now under Hardware section, click New button to add Camera hardware. It will open following Dialog box. Select Camera support from the Property dropdown and click Ok.
3. **Enable Camera Support in Hardware** 
   The new hardware: Camera support is visible under Hardware section. Set its value to yes and save changes by pressing Edit AVD.
4. **Save the changes and launch the emulator.**

Comment: any idea for Visual studio AVD ?

Comment: Please refer : https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/msft-android-emulator-vs.aspx

Answer (score 10):

You can try to manually edit your **AVD's configuration file** under

> ~/.android/avd/yourAvdName/config.ini

by adding this line:

```
hw.camera=yes
```

**UPDATE**

You can try to specify the **real resolution** of your webcam:

```
hw.camera.maxHorizontalPixels=XXX
hw.camera.maxVerticalPixels=XXX
```

Keep in mind that the default value for *maxHorizontalPixels* is **640** and for *maxVerticalPixels* is **480**, so chaning this values may help you to solve your issues.

Comment: We don't have the issue of activating the camera. The camera is activated, but there seems to be an issue with drivers. 

There camera works with VLC and cheese. But it does not work within  the emulator. However, the camera is detected by the system.

Comment: `hw.camera=yes` fixed my problem! Tks! Strangely, if you save your AVD configurations using the AVD manager, it removes the `hw.camera=yes` var. o.O

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with a slightly different error message under OS X. I turned out that everything was ok but the emulator is crashing when the camera takes too much time to initialize.

I my case I ended up closing other applications and it worked. You may want to test in a more performant computer.

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble getting the camera to work under the emulator (under linux), even after setting it up in AVD as instructed here. I was helped by noticing that the camera it was trying to use was /dev/video0, but the camera I wanted was /dev/video3. A quick swap...

```
mv /dev/video0 /dev/video4
mv /dev/video3 /dev/video0
```

...did the trick

[Change /dev/video6 into /dev/video0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19014041/change-dev-video6-into-dev-video0/19014134)