# Not Showing camera on button Click in emulator

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, android-camera

I'am trying to create an application whose purpose is to take picture on a button click.i am using an emulator to run the app. but the problem now is, when I click on the button nothing happens.

if anyone knows the solution please help.

**MAINACTIVITY.JAVA**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

    Camera camera;
    SurfaceView surfaceView;
    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    Button b1;
    Camera.PictureCallback rawCallback;
    Camera.ShutterCallback shutterCallback;
    Camera.PictureCallback jpegCallback;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                takepicture();
            }
        });
    }

    public void takepicture() {
        surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
        surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();

        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

        jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                FileOutputStream outStream = null;
                try {
                    outStream = new FileOutputStream(String.format("/sdcard/%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis()));
                    outStream.write(data);
                    outStream.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                }

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Picture Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                refreshCamera();
            }
        };
    }

    public void captureImage(View v) throws IOException {
        camera.takePicture(null, null, jpegCallback);
    }

    public void refreshCamera() {
        if (surfaceHolder.getSurface() == null) {
            return;
        }

        try {
            camera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        try {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            camera.startPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {
            camera = Camera.open();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
            return;
        }

        Camera.Parameters param;
        param = camera.getParameters();
        param.setPreviewSize(352, 288);
        camera.setParameters(param);

        try {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            camera.startPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e);
            return;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        refreshCamera();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.test.MainActivity" >


    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surfaceView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="camera"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="86dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MANIFEST**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

Comment: Have you enabled the camera in the emulator?

Comment: yes i've checked both emulatorcam and webcam but both not working.

Comment: If your target is API 23 you will need to request camera permission at runtime.

Comment: else try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28691796/2900127)